# Extreme values of a multivariable function lying on a helix

Tags: multivariable-calculus, extreme-value-theorem

Suppose I've a function $f(x,y,z)$ and a **helix**. There are *parameterised* points on the **helix** (using the parameter $t$) such that-

$\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:$ $x=cos(t)$ , $y=sin(t)$ , $z=t$

Now, the partial derivatives of $f$ at the given points are given by-

$\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:$ $f_x=cos(t)$ , $f_y=sin(t)$ , $f_z=t^2$

So, at what points on the **helix** can $f$ take an **extreme** value?

> My approach:

If the **helix** is represented by the curve $c(t)$, then $f(x,y,z)$ must be lying on $c(t)$. As a result, $f(cos(t),sin(t),t)$ must satisfy the helix $c(t)$, where each input in $f$ is a *function* of $t$. In that case, $f'(t)=\nabla f c'(t)$, thus fetching me $t^2$ as the output of $f'(t)$. For an extrema, $f'(t)=0$ is valid, so setting $t^2$ equal to zero, I get the required points as $(1,0,0)$.

> My doubt:

In reality, $f(x,y,z)$ doesn't have an **extremum**. But, how is this justifiable, when I do get a value of $t(=0)$ corresponding to an **extreme** value of $f$? Is it somewhat, an *inflection point* at $(1,0,0)$? Can someone help me out in this with a lucid explanation? Thanks.

Comment: A good method to approach this kind of problems is to verify the compactness of your constraint. Infact, since the constraint is a subset of $\mathbb R^n$, you can show that it is compact if it is bounded and closed. For Weirestrass, if it is compact, you know that the constraint $E$ will have  a min $m$ and a max $M$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your situation involves a function $(x,y,z)\mapsto f(x,y,z)$ and a helix $t\mapsto {\bf c}(t):=(\cos t,\sin t,t)$ in ${\mathbb R}^3$. You are told to study the composed function
$$g(t):=f\bigl({\bf c}(t)\bigr)\ .$$
You can view $f(x,y,z)$ as temperature at the point $(x,y,z)$ and $t\mapsto{\bf c}(t)$ as orbit of a space craft. The function $t\mapsto g(t)$ is then the temperature measured on the space craft.

By the chain rule and information given about $f$ one has
$$g'(t)=\nabla f\bigl({\bf c}(t)\bigr)\cdot{\bf c}'(t)=(\cos t,\sin t, t^2)(-\sin t,\cos t,1)=t^2\ .$$
This shows that $g'(t)\geq0$ for all $t$, and $=0$ only at $t=0$. It follows that $g$ is monotonically increasing. In fact $g(t)={1\over3}t^3+C$ for some constant $C$. When you draw the graph of $t$ you have an inflection point at $t=0$.

By the way: The function $f(x,y,z):={1\over2}(x^2+y^2)+{1\over3}z^3$ is an example for an $f$ described in the story.

Comment: I get it now! Thanks a lot! I'm new to calculus, can you tell me how to view an inflection point for a multivariable function as we used to do for a mono-varied one? How do we get to know if it's an **inflection pt.** or not for a multi-varied function?

Comment: The function $g$ is a one-variable function. – There are all sorts of critical points of multivariable functions. "Inflection point" is not one of them.